# Translate ssh tunneling command to Bitvise settings

Tags: linux, windows, ssh-tunnel

With the help of an expert, I have set up a ssh tunnel. The sever side is all set up (I own the sever), and I can use the following command the set up the client side (on Mac/Linux):

```
ssh -f johndoe@severip -L 8080:localhost:8008 -N
```

However, I don't understand the above command fully. (for example, I'm not sure if this is c2s or s2c) Now I want to set up the same thing for a Windows client. I want to use Bitvise as the ssh client, but I have no idea how to set it up.

**Question:** How to set up Bitvise so I can achieve the same thing as the above Linux command?

**Edit 1:** 
I set up and the proxy settings on Windows and Bitvise in the following way:
[image]
After I logged in through Bitvise, the browsers (both IE and Chrome in my case) will only return access denied. From the log of Bitvise, it seems that a lot things were going up, but it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

from `ssh(1)` man page

```
-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
         Specifies that the given port on the local (client) host is to be
         forwarded to the given host and port on the remote side.
```

so  `-L 8080:localhost:8008` will forward

- (client side) 8080
- to localhost on server serverip
- on port 8008.

I guess you want http:// localhost:8080 to map to http:// serverip:8008 (having no direct access from your client to serverip:8008 ).

you are on C2S (client 2 server ) .

last part from man page http://www.bitvise.com/port-forwarding

Comment: Thanks for explaining the option. Please see the updated question.